# spark streaming with sbt + cassandra connector dependency issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, sbt, spark-cassandra-connector

Folks,

I am trying to integrated cassandra with spark streaming. Below is the sbt file:

```
 scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.1",
"com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.6.2",
"com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.0.0",
("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.0").
exclude("org.spark-project.spark", "unused")
)
```

I added below line(error line mentioned below) for cassandra integration:

```
val lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[
String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
ssc, kafkaParams, topics)

//Getting errors once I add below line in program 
lines.saveToCassandra("test", "test", SomeColumns("key", "value"))

lines.print()
```

Once I add above line, I see below error in IDE:

[image]

I see similar error if i try to package this project from command prompt:

[image]

FYR, I am using below versions:

**scala** - 2.11

**kafka** - kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1

**java** - 8

**cassandra** - datastax-community-64bit_2.2.8

Please help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, it was dependency issue which is resolved by updating sbt file as below:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0",
"com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.0-RC1",
"com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.0.0",
("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.0").
exclude("org.spark-project.spark", "unused")
)
```